# How to avoid Hapi.js sending 400 error when Validating Request with Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, server, hapi.js

Hapi.js Validation with Joi + `failAction` question.

### Situation

We want to build a "*traditional*" **server-side**-***only***
rendered application using **Hapi**.

I'm trying to *understand* how to avoid returning a "*raw*" `400`
error to the client when `Joi` validation *fails*:

[image: register-iphone4s-sim]

We want to intercept this "*email not allowed to be empty*" **validation error** and display it in the html template back to the client,
instead of simply returning the `400` error.

[@AdriVanHoudt](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/725#issuecomment-144482794) advised that we should:

> "Look at failAction under http://hapijs.com/api#route-options "

So we added `failAction: 'log'` to the `/register` route handler:

```
{
  method: '*',
  path: '/register',
  config: {
    validate: {
      payload : register_fields,
      failAction: 'log'
    }
  },
  handler: register_handler
}
```

See code in:
[**server.js**](https://github.com/nelsonic/hapi-validation-question/blob/master/server.js)

the `register_handler` is:

```
function register_handler(request, reply, source, error) {
  console.log(request.payload);
  console.log(' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -');
  console.log(source)
  console.log(' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -');
  console.log(error)
  return reply('welcome!');
}
```

I am expecting to see an error in the terminal/console
but when I try to `console.log` the `handler` :

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
undefined
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
undefined
```

I asked the question on GitHub: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/725
but have not yet got an answer with a *good* ***example***.
Full code if you have time to help: https://github.com/nelsonic/hapi-validation-question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## There are *Two* Simple Solutions:

### 1. Use `server.ext('onPreResponse' ...`

As noted by @Clarkie a *generic* way of catching *all* errors in your Hapi App is to use `'onPreResponse'`.

We wrote a Hapi Plugin that does exactly that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-error

*As usual it has*:

[image: Build Status]
[image: codecov.io]
[image: Code Climate]
[image: Dependency Status]
[image: devDependency Status]
[image: HitCount]

And lets you define your own custom error pages in 3 easy steps.

#### 1. Install the [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-error) from npm:

```
npm install hapi-error --save
```

#### 2. Include the plugin in your Hapi project

Include the plugin when you `register` your server:

> See: [/example/server_example.js](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-error/blob/master/example/server_example.js) for simple example

#### 3. Ensure that you have a View called `error_template`

> Note: `hapi-error` plugin *expects* you are using [`Vision`](https://github.com/hapijs/vision) (*the standard view rendering library for Hapi apps*)
>   which allows you to use Handlebars, Jade, React, etc. for your templates.

Your `error_template.html` (*or `error_template.ext` `error_template.jsx`*) should make use of the 3 variables it will be passed:

- `errorTitle` - *the error tile generated by Hapi*
- `statusCode` - *HTTP statusCode sent to the client *e.g: `404`* (*not found*)
- `errorMessage` - the *human-friendly error message*

> for an example see: [`/example/error_template.html`](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-error/blob/master/example/error_template.html)

*That's it*!

[image: hapi-error-screens]

### 2. Use `failAction`

[image: Build Status]
[image: codecov.io]
[image: Code Climate]
[image: HitCount]

We added `failAction` which ***re-uses*** the `register_handler`
so that the `registration-form.html` is shown with any input validation error message (*until it is submitted with valid data*)

```
{
  method: '*',
  path: '/register',
  config: {
    validate: {
      payload : register_fields,
      failAction: register_handler // register_handler is dual-purpose (see below!)
    }
  },
  handler: register_handler
}
```

the `register_handler` is:

```
function register_handler(request, reply, source, error) {
  // show the registration form until its submitted correctly
  if(!request.payload || request.payload && error) {
    var errors, values; // return empty if not set.
    if(error && error.data) { // means the handler is dual-purpose
      errors = extract_validation_error(error); // the error field + message
      values = return_form_input_values(error); // avoid wiping form data
    }
    return reply.view('registration-form', {
      title  : 'Please Register ' + request.server.version,
      error  : errors, // error object used in html template
      values : values  // (escaped) values displayed in form inputs
    }).code(error ? 400 : 200); // HTTP status code depending on error
  }
  else { // once successful, show welcome message!
    return reply.view('welcome-message', {
      name   : validator.escape(request.payload.name),
      email  : validator.escape(request.payload.email)
    })
  }
}
```

> See: [**server.js**:57](https://github.com/nelsonic/hapi-validation-question/blob/master/server.js#L57) for complete file.

Where `extract_validation_error(error)` and `return_form_input_values(error)`
are helper functions defined within `server.js` (*but would be split out into re-useable view helpers*) which keep our handler function lean.

When we submit the form without any of the required fields we see:

[image: register-1of4]

[image: register-3of4]

We also use https://github.com/chriso/validator.js
to mitigate [Cross Site Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)
vulnerability:

[image: register-hack-1of2]

And display a welcome message on successful registration:
[image: reg-success-1of2]

### Conclusion

We feel that re-using the handler function as the `failAction`
keeps the code related to this route/action in a single place
whereas `server.ext('onPreResponse' ...` (*while appropriate on initial inspection*) will introduce "*hooks*"
which *can* be a source of confusion (*once an app has many such hooks...*)

### #YMMV

Let us know what you think! [image: Join the chat at https://gitter.im/dwyl/chat]

Answer (score 6):

You should look at implementing an error handler in the `onPreResponse` [extension point](http://hapijs.com/api#requests).

> The response contained in request.response may be modified (but not assigned a new value). To return a different response type (for example, replace an error with an HTML response), return a new response via reply(response). Note that any errors generated after reply(response) is called will not be passed back to the `onPreResponse` extension method to prevent an infinite loop.

A simple example:

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {
  if (request.response.statusCode === 400 ){
    return reply('summat else');
  }
  return reply.continue();
});
```

Comment: the `server.ext('onPreResponse' ...` is certainly a good way of intercepting the validation error, but we have decided to follow Matt Harrison's suggestion and use the `failAction`. thanks for your answer! :-)